# Sequelize - Delete all data before some hours from now

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Node.js and Sequelize / Maria DB
What I want to do is delete all data in a table before some hours from now.

(So. the logic is 'IF createdAt is before X hours from now, delete all row.)

I've been searching nice examples through google, and stackoverflow, but I could not find solution yet.

My code is like this.

```
    const expireDate = 24

    await MyTable.destroy({
        where: {
            createdAt: ...
        }
    })
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to use moment.

```
const expiryDate = 24;
const { Op } = require('sequelize');

await MyTable.destroy({
    where: {
        createdAt: {[Op.lte]: moment().subtract(expiryDate, 'hours').toDate()}
    }
});
```

Comment: Definitely do not need moment for that. `new Date(Date.now() - (60*60*24*1000 /* 24hrs in ms */))` will give you the same result.